# PHP Sessions - Locking and Sharing questions

Tags: php, session

I would like to know if it is possible to read $_SESSION attributes without locking it.
Currently, `session_start()` locks SESSION, that means other PHP processes will wait until it is unlocked.
But, some processes just want to get some $_SESSION variables, not to write on them.
Is that possible to implement some function like `session_get(string $id)` which doesn't lock SESSION?

Also, it is possible to share SESSIONs between browsers, once the user is logged in the same account, for example, using `session_id('shared_vars_of_'.$userid)`. But, is that secure? Is this discouraged?

Thanks,
Nuno

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting question!

[session_write_close()](http://www.php.net/session_write_close) is not exactly what you're asking for but it should help speed up the process:

> Session data is usually stored after your script terminated without the need to call session_write_close(), but as session data is locked to prevent concurrent writes only one script may operate on a session at any time. When using framesets together with sessions you will experience the frames loading one by one due to this locking. You can reduce the time needed to load all the frames by ending the session as soon as all changes to session variables are done.

A script that needs only read-only access could start the session, copy the session variables into another array and apply session_write_close(). It won't be a fully read-only solution - it could be that you'd need to build your own session handler for that - but it should be a big step forward.

**Update:** I just found an [interesting issue from 2001 in the PHP 4 tracker](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=8978) that seems to introduce a patch enabling read only sessions - it doesn't seem to have made it to the official releases, though, at least not according to the documentation! Maybe it's worth digging further or reopening the Ticket for PHP 5.

Comment: Actually, I know about that function and I use it already. So, from your answer, I assume it is not possible to have a read-only solution. Thanks Pekka.

Comment: @Nuno not as far as I can see, no, not without taking session handling completely in your own hands.

Answer (score 6):

Personally I do this right at the start:

```
session_start();
session_write_close();
```

And then you have access to $_SESSION as read-only. As you can see below, *you do not need to copy the session variables*.

```
session_start();
//This value will be "The #1 Value!" only the 2nd time you run this
echo "<br />myData value1:".$_SESSION['myData'];
$_SESSION['myData'] = "Value 2 and 3!";
session_write_close();

echo "<br />myData value2 (read-only):".$_SESSION['myData'];
$_SESSION['myData'] = "Value 3 Misleading, and never actually written to the session!";
//But it will affect this value, obviously
echo "<br />myData value3:".$_SESSION['myData'];

session_start();
//NOTE HOW THE ABOVE LINE WRITES-OVER $_SESSION
echo "<br />myData value4:".$_SESSION['myData'];
$_SESSION['myData'] = "The #1 Value!";
session_write_close();
```

Comment: This actually introduces all the concurrency problems that session locking aims to solve: if a second request tries to alter the session while the first request is using it read-only (the part between `session_write_close`  and `session_start`), only the first script’s changes will actually persist. That’s because it will write the whole session with the changed values (good) as well as the values loaded when the script had started (which include the keys that were changed by the second script).

Comment: Note that opening and closing session takes some time (especially for large sessions) and will make your script slower. e.g. `foreach (...) { process(); session_start(); write_progress(); session_write_close(); }` will be very slow!

Comment: @RaphaelSchweikert session_start() takes care of locks and waits until the other script performs session_write_close()