# PHP foreach user script seems to make apache hang

Tags: php, mysql

I've made a very simple script to loop through all of our users with a limit of 500 per execution.

It does the following:

1. Select user data
2. Inserts a row
3. Emails the user
4. Updates a Row
5. Next user

**It works as intended and completes successfully.**

However when I run it I cannot use the website in another window because it just 'loads' until this script has finished executing?

It's as if the script locks the user table whilst it's running but this shouldn't happen because we're just using the data saved to `$result`?

But I can query the database through sqlyog while the website freezes so it can't be that? Could it just be using too many resources?

**The Script** - Example

```
<?
set_time_limit(0);

require '../connect.php';
require '../includes/ses.php';

$i = 1;

$ses = new simpleemailservice();

$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, username, email FROM `user` WHERE thiscol = 0 LIMIT 500");

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (data) VALUES (1)");

    $m = new SimpleEmailServiceMessage();

        $m->addTo($row[1]." <".$row[2].">");
        $m->setFrom("Emailer <no-reply@emailer.com>");
        $m->setSubject("Subject");
        $m->setMessageFromString("Email Text", "Email HTML");

    if($ses->sendEmail($m))
        mysql_query("UPDATE `user` SET thiscol = 1 WHERE id = ".$row[0]);

    $i++;
}
?>
```

Comment: Call `session_write_close();` if you're planning to do something that will take a while longer. Other `session_start()`'s _block_ until your long running process has released its lock on you session. Better yet: don't start a session if you don't need it, always close it when you are sure you will not write any data to it.

Comment: @Wrikken Perfect, it was the `session_start()` in connect.php, never run into that before

Comment: @Wrikken That is an answer not a comment. So if you don't post it, I will ;-)  (And, as you can guess, I agree, this sounds like session locking.)

Comment: @DarrenCook: that's a deal, it's 2:00 here, I'm not really the mood to formulate a good answer with links to the documentation anymore, so, go ahead & post the answer, and I'll turn in here ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour sounds like session-locking. The default way PHP sessions work is to lock the session (to prevent two processes writing to the session object). This is normally fine for typical short-lived PHP scripts, but can bite you when you have something that is long-running.

If your application is not using sessions at all, then you should turn off `session.auto_start` in php.ini or .htaccess: http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start
(If you don't see it there, or it is already off, but you are using some kind of framework, the framework might be starting the session for you; if so it is simpler to go to the next solution than try to fight the framework.)

If you are using the session on some pages, but not on this long-running process, the solution is to close the session at the start of your script, with [session_write_close()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php):

```
<?
set_time_limit(0);

require '../connect.php';
require '../includes/ses.php';

session_write_close();

$i = 1;
....
```

Again, the framework warning: if the framework is starting a session for you, then put `session_write_close();` after including the framework files, not before! (You mentioned that was the case in your comments, which is why I've put it after the require lines.)

If your long-running process needs to use the session, but read-only, the above still works. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14409902/841830
(As that answer shows, if you need to write to the session at the end of the long-running process, that is also possible.)

(P.S. This was already answered in the comments, but I've taken Wrikken up on his offer to post it as an answer. Yes, the rumours are true: I'll do anything for a few rep...)