# Is a loop returning multiple value required on server side events?

Tags: php, eventsource

I'm trying to learn [server side events](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp) on php.

At first almost every example had a loop in the server side and returning value with ob_flush() / flush(). So I tryed doing like this:

```
<?php

  header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
  header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

  // Output a 'waiting message'
  $progress = 0;

  while ($progress < 100) {
     echo 'data:';
     echo $progress;
     echo "\n\n";
     flush();
     ob_flush(); //I tried ob_implicit_flush(true) too
     $progress++;
     sleep(1);
  }

?>
```

And javascript :

```
   function start(btn) {    

     var source = new EventSource('/fix/streamingGet.php');

     source.onmessage = function(e) {
         console.log(e.data);
     };

   }
```

<strike>But nothing was received until the script was ended ...
so i ended up trying without an infinite loop and everything is working</strike>

```
<?php

      header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
      header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

      // Output a 'waiting message'
      echo 'data:';
      echo rand(5, 15);
      echo "\n\n";

?>
```

Edit: Nevermind, I probably did a mistake somewhere before because now it work

Edit : I meant a loop returning multiple result with ob_flush/flush (not infinite loop, my bad)

But do I need to return my data with multiple flush to gain performance with [Server Side Envents](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp) ?

**Update :**

From my tests and researches, it seem that php doesn't allow multiple session which make the first example to block any other call to the server. So the only working php solution seem to return value everytimes. Which I think is the same of having multiple timed ajax call to the server.

I am guessing that if I really want to stream a value from the server then I should probably use nodejs on the side of my webapplication.

Comment: "I'm trying to learn serverside events on php" What do you mean by this? What events?

Comment: What you are saying makes very little sense... There is no infinite loop here. If you had an infinite loop your program would crash due to some memory-related fatal error. Let's take a step back. What are you trying to do with your learning-example?

Comment: PHP does not update the page live as it is not client-side so yes you *will have to wait for the script to end in order to get a return*. what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I think my first mistake was because I did echo the "data:" before the loop and the "\n\n" after the loop but now it work.

I changed "infinite loop" to "loop returning multiple value"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is basically correct.

But put `ob_flush()` before `flush()` (because `ob_flush()` flushes PHP buffers to Apache, and then `flush()` tells Apache to send *its* buffered content to the client) and it is more robust to put `@` before `ob_flush()` (because if you have turned off PHP buffering, you might get an error message - the `@` suppresses that).

(The comments are wrong about using infinite loops in PHP: they are fine in this case. When the browser client disconnects, Apache will kill the PHP instance. There is no memory leak just from running an infinite/long-running loop.)

PHP sessions lock. So if the same user (the same session) might access some other part of your site while the SSE script is sending data, you need the SSE script to stop using sessions. So, grab any data you need from the session at the top of your script, then call `session_write_close()` before entering your main loop. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19440378/841830

Comment: THX ! I did'nt know about the session_write_close() now it work :)